# Liferay 7 with IBM Java javax.crypto error

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7, javax.crypto

Attempting to run Liferay 7 bundle on z, SLES12, with IBM Java 8. I'm getting the following error when running startup.sh:

```
27-Jan-2017 17:00:14.652 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /data/liferay/tomcat-8.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateManifestResources ExtensionValidator[][file:/data/liferay/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]: Required extension [javax.crypto] not found.
27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.343 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateManifestResources ExtensionValidator[]: Failure to find [1] required extension(s).
27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.343 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.344 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.349 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)

27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.352 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /data/liferay/tomcat-8.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml has finished in 699 ms
27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 752 ms
27-Jan-2017 17:00:15.356 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:417)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:444)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

   .main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxz6480sr3fp21-20161117_02(SR3 FP21))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux s390x-64 Compressed References 20161114_325917 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_20161114_0146_B325917
JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20161111_127476
GC   - R28_20161114_0146_B325917_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20161114_325917)
JCL - 20161116_01 based on Oracle jdk8u111-b14
```

I cannot seem to clear the

> Required extension [javax.crypto] not found

error and am wondering if anyone knows if:

1. IBM Java is compatible with Liferay 7
2. there is a way to use the Oracle Java security package in place of IBM's

If anyone has any information as to how I can get Liferay 7 up and running in the current environment, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kill any process running on 8005

Answer (score 0):

Ans 2. javax.crypto package should be present in IBM java - in rt.jar. Replacing this directly with Oracle package may break IBM java class library functionality as they have slightly different structure and implementation.

Comment: Ideally IBM Java SE should not have any problem running anything that runs on Oracle Java SE. I am wondering if the startup script has dependency which relies on Oracle Java class structure. I will check if I can find anything.

Comment: Thank you imkabir... see my note above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. We resolved the issue by removing a MANIFEST.MF (within Liferay 7's bundled Tomcat directory) file that was specifically referencing Oracle Java's crypto.  When we removed that file it started up without the error.  Since then, we tend to see a message in the logs to the effect of 'Oracle's crypto file is not found, using IBM's instead'.

No other issues present on start up.